# Excel Column B has duplicates and only 1 row has value in Column A for each set of duplicates in B, return something to identify there is a match

Tags: excel, duplicates, lookup

Excel Formula (non VBA preferred)
Column B has duplicates and only 1 row has value in Column A for each set of duplicates in column B.
Need to return "something"/True/False/wtvr in column C to identify there is a value in A and B anywhere for the duplicate values in column B, leaving items without something in Column A blank.

[image: Example with desired outcome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy using `COUNTIFS`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,A:A,"<>")>0,"something","")
```

If column A contains a formula that returns a null string (`""`), something like:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$18=B2)*(LEN(A$2:A$18)>0))>0,"something","")
```

where `B$2:B$18` and `A$2:A$18` represent the ranges with data.